# How to write and parse "yaml" file for ROS?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml-cpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

My goal is to subscribe to an "unknown" number of topics. I want to do the next algorithm:

1. Create a "yaml" file for ROS, where all my topics are listed.
2. Extract it´s data as a string.
3. Parse the data, according to which I will know the number and the names of the topics to which I want to subscribe.
4. Subscribe in a loop to all of them.

The problem is that I have never written a "yaml" file, and the explanations in the Wikipedia page are not good for ROS.
I would also be happy to know what is the best way to "parse" the info in my code (C).

Thank you for your help,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12321/how-to-write-and-parse-%22yaml%22-file-for-ros?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, ROS itself uses yaml-cpp, so that's not a bad way to go about it.

Second, I'd like to propose an alternative way to solve your problem (since I've just done the same thing myself). `roslaunch` supports all forms of XmlRpc values, including lists. Therefore, you can use the following code:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue topicList;
std::vector<std::string> topics;

if (private_nh.getParam("topics", topicList))
{
  std::map<std::string, XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue>::iterator i;
  for (i = topicList.begin(); i != topicList.end(); i++)
  {
    std::string topic_name;
    std::string topic_type;

    topic_name = i->first;
    topic_type.assign(i->second["topic_type"]);

    topics.push_back(topic_name);
  }
}
```

Essentially, this code will read all parameters that are under the "topics" namespace into a single list. You then iterate through that list to grab all topic names. Each new topic can have as many sub-fields (topic_type) as you desire. Here's an example launchfile statement for the above code.

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="my_package" type="my_node" name="my_node" output="screen">
        <param name="topics/topic1/topic_type" type="string" value="sensor_msgs/LaserScan" />
        <param name="topics/topic2/topic_type" type="string" value="sensor_msgs/PointCloud2" />
    </node>
</launch
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-12-13**:
Hello Dimitri, many thanks for your detailed answer, but since I am not very fluent in C++, I will try first to do it in the second way proposed here (which doesn´t really works well now http://answers.ros.org/question/3297/how-to-convert-xmlrpcxmlrpcvalue-into-string). Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example yaml file you can use to specify topic names to be connected to:

```
topics:
    - topic1
    - topic2
    - topic3
    - topic4
```

What you see here is a map with one key "topics", its value is a list with 4 string elements. That's pretty much all you need to know about yaml syntax to cover 90% use cases in ROS (both reading and writing config files).

To read those topic names in a ROS node using roscpp, see [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server) page. Scroll all the way down to "Retrieving Lists".

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-12-13**:
Hi arebgun, I think your suggestion worked well, except the last part...I have some problems there: http://answers.ros.org/question/3297/how-to-convert-xmlrpcxmlrpcvalue-into-string. If you have any idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use yaml-cpp along with ROS2. Just add following codes to your `package.xml`, `CMakeLists.txt` and `source file`:

**Package.xml:**

```
<build_depend>yaml-cpp</build_depend>
<build_export_depend>yaml-cpp</build_export_depend>
<exec_depend>yaml-cpp</exec_depend>
```

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
include_directories(HEADERS_EXECUTABLE
    ${YAML_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    yaml-cpp
)
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("[Name Of File].yaml");

    if (config["SOMETHING"]) {
      std::cout << config["SOMETHING"] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can find more information about yaml-cpp [here](https://yaml-cpp.docsforge.com/master/tutorial/).

---

Originally posted by [Technerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/41627/technerd/) with karma: 41 on 2020-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4